# copy chown doesn't work if directories permissions are root:root

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, permissions, root, chown

Very interesting thing happens to me. I'm beginner and maybe that's why I DON'T GET it.

I have project which has 5 folders in it. the permissions of those folders are `root:root` . now I have a dockerfile and in that file I got something like this :

```
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
```

so what this should do is my project's permissions in /var/www in container has to change to www:www.

1) It doesn't work when host's directory's(my project) permissins are root:root

2) it works when I change my host's directory's permissions(my project) to anything else such as `user_test:user_test.`

Please tell me why. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can we assume this is a question about `docker`? if so it should probably be tagged as such

Comment: what I said doesn't happen in ordinary linux?

Comment: Well AFAIK "ordinary linux" doesn't have a direct equivalent of the `COPY --chown` command (`cp` can optionally *preserve* ownership, but not change it)

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili What do you mean by "ordinary linux" ?